# Is the CSV download link API stable (or official)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-export-url

Is this a part of a stable api? Can I use it in an app to consume the data?

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?gid=<WORKBOOK_ID>&format=csv`

Comment: @pnuts I'm wondering if that was because the question had only one tag or because the title failed to attract the attention of others. I found it because I was scanning the unanswered questions of the google-spreadsheet tag.

Comment: What would be a more appropriate tag for this question?

Comment: Thank you, I added the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?gid=<WORKBOOK_ID>&format=csv` is not part of a current API.

The Google Sheets API documentation link is

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: Rubén, any way to predict/anticipate breaking changes in this case?

Comment: @aaandre subscribe/follow/join to the appropriate channel from Google Developers. You can found them at the bottom of the referred page.

Answer (score 1):

I think the then-working solutions no longer work reliably.  sometimes they do, sometimes they do not.

```
#!/bin/bash

u='1VaW8fRFJeJ5Wg6-prF8l3xCwbjkx-q_Mqyt8XfjIn6Q'

echo "pubhtml"
curl -s "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$u/pubhtml"  | grep -c 'exists to test'

echo "export1"
curl -s "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$u/export?format=csv&id=$u"  | grep -c 'exists to test'
echo "export2"
curl -s "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$u/export?format=csv&gid=$u"  | grep -c 'exists to test'
echo "export3"
curl -s "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$u/export?format=csv&gid=0"  | grep -c 'exists to test'
echo "export4"
curl -s "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=$u&gid=1&tq=select%20A,%20B&tqx=reqId:1;out:html;%20responseHandler:webQuery" | grep -c "exists to test"
echo "export5"
curl -s "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=$u&id=1&tq=select%20A,%20B&tqx=reqId:1;out:html;%20responseHandler:webQuery" | grep -c "exists to test"
exit 0
```

(my test spreadsheet contains the string.)  only the first request (pubhtml) still works.  that is, my CL output is `1 0 0 0 0 0` .  so, short of using .net or java, the current working choice seems to be pubhtml and reparsing its HTML?

shame---it was such a useful easy way to pull down data.

/iaw